# LangChain + Hugging Face -> HuggingFacePIpeline Error

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, langchain, huggingface

I'm trying to do the following simple code:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
import langchain
from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline

model_name = "bert-base-uncased"
task = "question-answering"

hf_pipeline = pipeline(task, model=model_name)

langchain_pipeline = HuggingFacePipeline(hf_pipeline)
```

I get the following error:

- ERROR: `TypeError: Serializable.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`
- LINE: `langchain_pipeline = HuggingFacePipeline(hf_pipeline)`

> Haven't found anything online that actually helped me here

---

I'm using Databricks with the following cluster:

- Runtime: 12.2 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)
- Node type: Standard_DS5_v2   56 GB Memory, 16 Cores
- Libraries: [image: cluster2libraries]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code example

```py
# from transformers import pipeline
# import langchain
from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFacePipeline

model_name = "bert-base-uncased"
# task = "question-answering"
task = "text-generation"

# hf_pipeline = pipeline(task, model=model_name)

langchain_pipeline = HuggingFacePipeline.from_model_id(
    model_name,
    task,
)
```

And `only ('text2text-generation', 'text-generation', 'summarization') are supported`

`HuggingFacePipeline` doc for reference > https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/huggingface_pipelines

Comment: (1) Why can't I use it with the `pipeline`? even with summarization

(2) with your code I get the following error: `ValueError: Unrecognized configuration class <class 'transformers.models.bert.configuration_bert.BertConfig'> for this kind of AutoModel: AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.`

Comment: (1) You can use it. However if you want to use LangChain, `HuggingFacePipeline` is the one to call. (2) the error message comes from `transformers`. You should comment out it if not using it. I add another code snippet in my previous answer. If you insist on using `transformers` with such model, here's the reference > https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased

Comment: The model is just an example for testing it will not be the final model that I will use, but my goal is to have a model from hugging face used on top of langchain (the model will be an instruct LLM) and my goal is to use it to perform analysis and prompt engineering on some files. *What will be your suggestions?*

Comment: For `text-generation` purpose, I would recommend `GPT4All`, which is `mistral-7b`, and `tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct`

Comment: (1) The `mistral-7b` doesnt work for me, can you share an example on it? (2) in your answer you gave a ref to the langchain website, in it the use `from langchain_community.llms.huggingface_pipeline import HuggingFacePipeline` and not `from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline` why is that?

Comment: 1. I wrote a blog > https://j3ffyang.medium.com/document-summarization-with-retriever-in-langchain-e016d3ffe108 to describe how `GPT4All` can be deployed locally. 2. LangChain categorized `llms` into `langchain_community`, more speficifically > https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/llms/langchain_community.llms.huggingface_pipeline.HuggingFacePipeline.html